# How is change metricized in the rankings?

Tags: discussion, top-users, rankings

When I look at the change score in the ranking, it's either a ridiculously large number or a ridiculously small number so it's obviously not Δreputation. So what exactly is it?  How is it calculated?

Comment: Which page are you looking at?

Comment: The top weekly ranking page in the summery in my profile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean the second column,

[image]

don't you?

That is the change in places, the person currently ranked 65<sup>th</sup> in this years league was ranked 168<sup>th</sup> last year, so climbed up 103 places.

Comment: So I must be reaching the top fast. Mine moved up 26,000.

Comment: I see `+23271` for you this week. In the week rankings, you can not only gain places fast, but also lose. Even Jon Skeet sometimes drops below tenth in the week rankings (on Sundays, maybe even Mondays, not at the end of the week).

Comment: Who is John Skeet?

Comment: [He](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s the Chuck Norris of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Jon Skeet doesn't give answers. He pre-empts questions.

Comment: The really should relabel "change" to "rank change" or "change in rank".